# How to change text size of spinner befor selection

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I know using custom layout i we can chance drop down item and spinner item but that only work after selection.
But i dont find any example that can show how to change text size of spinner befor selection

Comment: what do you mean by "before" and "after" selection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change Android Spinner text size by passing in a custom layout, instead of using Android default layout like simple_spinner_item. Here's a new Android layout XML file created in `res/layout` folder.

**spinner_text_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:padding="4dp" />
```

Pass the `spinner_text_item` layout to ArrayAdapter's constructor.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.spinner_text_item, list);

// assign adapter to Spinner
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
```

It doesn't matter it is **before** or **after** drop down selection is made (as you mentioned), once the adapter (with custom layout) is set to the spinner, spinner item is styled according to the custom layout.